# surface book vmware workstation 12 bridging to wireless nic not working with linux guest

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I have a Microsoft Surface Book running VMware Workstation 12 on Windows 10 host. I need to run Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest with its single nic bridged to the SB's physical wireless adapter. In the virtual network editor I tried both Automatic as well as manually configuring the virtual interface to bridge to the SB's wireless adapter (Marvell AVASTAR AC) but the linux guest nic does not get any DHCP or automatic address neither it works with a manual ip configuration.

ifconfig looks nothing special:

ens33 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0c:29:05:xx:xx:xx
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:21564 (21.5 KB)

Everything works fine when I bridge to the wired nic (on the SB this requires a USB adapter).

By the way I tried this in VirtualBox as well with no luck.